# How to check_password() with salt?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem. I am creating a user by:
`User.objects.create(..., password=make_password(data['password'], salt='some_salt')`.

That's okay, but how can I check password with this salt? A can't add salt in `check_password()` method.

Comment: You don't have to use the salt in the checking algorithm, since it is stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are normally **stored *with* the salt**. Indeed, as is specified in the [documentation on *How Django stores passwords*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords):

Django provides a flexible password storage system and uses PBKDF2 by default.

The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

So if you inspect the `password` field of your user, you will indeed see something like:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$150000$somesalt$7b6ZYSY/8i82eF5POcHJcDXQAE2qzC3DtHtcIOtVTVw=
```

This is exactly what the `make_password` function will return:

```
>>> make_password('password', salt='somesalt')
'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$somesalt$7b6ZYSY/8i82eF5POcHJcDXQAE2qzC3DtHtcIOtVTVw='
```

You can make use of the [**`authenticate(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) to log in, for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='guy', password='password')
```

If the authentication succeeds, `user` will be a user object (with the user model you specified, or Django's user model by default), if not `user` is `None`.